# Animating a Sprite After Mouse Release - SFML

Tags: c++

I'm working on a game where the user can drag and release sprites. After the sprite is released it should interpolate (animate) back to its original position. So I researched on the math relevant to implement the concept in the game. To demonstrate my point, here's the code of a console app I wrote:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "vec2.h"
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    m::vec2 posA { 0.f, 0.f };
    m::vec2 posB { 10.f, 10.f };

    m::vec2 B_to_A = posA - posB; // (-10, -10)

    float length = m::length(B_to_A); // 14.1421

    m::vec2 normalizedVec = B_to_A / length; // (-0.707107, -0.707107)

    float lengthOfUnitVec = m::length(normalizedVec); // 1
```

I tried to emulate the update function of the game:

```
    float loopLength = length;

    size_t i = 0;
    while(loopLength > 0)
    {
        posB += normalizedVec;
        cout << posB << endl;
        cout << i << endl;
        ++i;
        loopLength -= lengthOfUnitVec;
    }
```

The loop executes 14 times when `loopLength` is negative.
As you can see my plan was to defined a variable for the distance until point A is reached. Also, the position of B is changing as the distance decreases.

The problem is that when I release the sprite it doesn't return exactly to where it was originally.

My guess is that it has to do with floating-point numbers but I just can't come up with a solution. Another speculation is it is because the user can release at any position. Therefore, there's always an extra offset.

Notice, here I used a simple case where the distance is (-10, -10) and a normalized velocity. When I try to scale the velocity `normalizedVec` for moving faster the gap is larger. Maybe I will post Part 2 when I try to implement using your advices in SFML. I appreciate any help.

**Solution in SFML:**

```
#include "Game.h"
#include "ResourcePath.hpp"
#include <SFML/Graphics/Texture.hpp>
#include <SFML/Window/Event.hpp>

using namespace std;

Game::Game()
: window(sf::VideoMode(640, 480), "SFML")
, frameRate(sf::seconds(1.f / 60.f))
, sprite{}
, shape{}
, isAnimating{ false }
, isSelected{ false }
, texture{}
, speed{ 0.1f }
, targetPos{sf::Vector2f{ 30.f, 30.f} }
{
    window.setVerticalSyncEnabled(true);

    texture.loadFromFile(resourcePath() + "sprite.png");
    shape.setPosition(targetPos);
    shape.setOutlineColor(sf::Color::Red);
    shape.setOutlineThickness(1.f);
    shape.setFillColor(sf::Color::Transparent);
    shape.setSize(static_cast<sf::Vector2f>(texture.getSize()));
    sprite.setTexture(texture);
    sprite.setPosition(targetPos);
}

void Game::draw()
{
    window.clear();

    window.draw(shape);
    window.draw(sprite);

    window.display();
}

void Game::processEvents()
{
    sf::Event event;
    while (window.pollEvent(event))
    {
        // Close window: exit
        if (event.type == sf::Event::Closed)
        {
            window.close();
        }

        if (event.type == sf::Event::MouseButtonPressed)
        {
            if (sprite.getGlobalBounds()
                .contains(event.mouseButton.x, event.mouseButton.y))
            {
                isSelected = true;
                isAnimating = false;
            }
        }

        if (event.type == sf::Event::MouseButtonReleased)
        {
            isSelected = false;
            isAnimating = true;
        }

        // Escape pressed: exit
        if (event.type == sf::Event::KeyPressed 
            && event.key.code == sf::Keyboard::Escape)
        {
            window.close();
        }
    }

}

void Game::update(sf::Time dt)
{
    if (isAnimating)
    {
        sprite.move((targetPos - sprite.getPosition()) * speed );
    }

    if (isSelected)
    {
        sprite.setPosition(static_cast<sf::Vector2f>(sf::Mouse::getPosition(window)));
    }

}

void Game::run()
{
    sf::Clock clock;
    sf::Time dt = sf::Time::Zero;
    while (window.isOpen())
    {
        processEvents();
        dt += clock.restart();
        while (dt > frameRate)
        {
            dt -= frameRate;
            processEvents();
            update(frameRate);
        }
        draw();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this algorithm? It also provide a smooth movement.
First declare the animaton speed and the previous position of the sprite (where it should go after the mouse release):

```
float Speed = 0.1f; //animation speed, adjust as you like
Vector2 TargetPos; //The previous position of the sprite or just the position where the sprite should move after mouse release
TargetPos.x = PreviousPosition.x; //or some test values, e.g. 300
TargetPos.y = PreviousPosition.y;
// I dont know your vector class. Imagine this:
/*
struct Vector2
{
  float x;
  float y;
};
*/
```

Update in each frame (in the update loop) the animation (the actual sprite position), but only if the mouse button is released (or whenever you like):

```
//Pseudocode
if(Mouse.leftBtnReleased)
{
    Sprite.Position.x += (TargetPos.x - Sprite.Position.x) * Speed;
    Sprite.Position.y += (TargetPos.y - Sprite.Position.y) * Speed;
}
```

What it actually does is that the sprite is moving constantly (if the mouse button is released) towards the `TargetPos`-position but the further the sprite is away from this point the faster it moves. This creates a smooth animation. Also quite useful for camera zooming and follow camera movement e.g. in platformer games. You can adjust the `Speed` value as you like.

Comment: Actually I already achieved smooth animation. I moved the sprite, smoothly, from the point B back to point A. However, the sprite doesn't stop exactly where it was; it goes off by some number of pixels, depending on the velocity.

Comment: probably its beacuse of the (relatively) low accuracy of floats over the calculations you do. Once I had the same problem and I solved it with this algorithm. Another method is to set the position of the sprite to **exactly** the position you want to archive after the (in your example case) emulated update loop succeeds.

Comment: I'll try your algorithm. If it works for me, I'll post the code and accept your answer.

Comment: The algorithm works well. There's another problem, in my game I am using a pointer to selectable entities, I need to know when the animation is over so that I can set the pointer to `nullptr` or `NULL`.

Comment: Check if the actual position of the sprite matches the previous position. If so you can set the pointer to `NULL`. Eventually you can set a range for the detection, e.g. a offset of `0.0001` is allowed and then before setting the pointer to `NULL` you set the position of the sprite to the targeted position. On this way the sprite moves to **exactly** the position from there it comes.

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply. I think it would take some time to implement it. Thankfully, I found an easier way. The problem was if there's no object detected the previous object is still being pointed to and it would animate even though it shouldn't. I fixed the problem by setting the pointer to `nullptr` if no object is selected.